# Netbeans, show memory usage on startup

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

To manually show the memory usage widget on Netbeans Platform, I have to right click on the toolbar and then select Memory.

Is there a way to get the memory usage widget to be shown on start up as default? Such that it will be displayed on startup without user input.

Comment: I have Netbeans 7.0.1, and after I right-click to show the memory widget, close netbeans, then reopen it the memory widget is still there.  So that's not the case for you?

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to deploy the netbeans platform with the memory usage displayed as a default without having the user to manually do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading I found that there is a property that can be set in the Core UI module.

In the package explorer:
- Important Files | XML Layer |  | Toolbars | Standard

Set:`<Toolbar name="Memory" visible="true">`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this setting is saved in the User's directory, where their Netbeans preferences are saved.  This wouldn't be a "deployable" solution but the following shows you where the setting is stored http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

I verified this with Windows 7 and Netbeans 7.0.1.  The file you're looking for is `.netbeans/7.0/config/Toolbars/Standard.xml`.  Inside this you should see a line like `<Toolbar name="Memory" visible="false" draggable="true" align="left"/>`, make sure "visible" is set to `"true"`, save the file, then start Netbeans.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am looking for a means to preset it to true when the user first starts the netbeans platform.